# Как разбить один массив на несколько?

Tags: php

Есть такой массив

```
Array
(
    [0] => Площадь:
    [1] => 3028 м2
    [2] => Тип дома:
    [3] => Каменный
    [4] => Вид дома:
    [5] => Не указан
    [6] => Количество этажей:
    [7] => 5
    [8] => Подвал:
    [9] => На весь дом
    [10] => Гараж:
    [11] => Не указано
    [12] => Крыша:
    [13] => 1-скатная (плоская)
    [14] => Стиль:
    [15] => Современные
    [16] => Хиты продаж:
    [17] => Не указано
    [18] => Год:
    [19] => После 2015
    [20] => Цена:
    [21] => не указано
)
```

По логике понятно, что каждый первый элемент это название, каждый второй - это значение.

Как это массив превратить в вид:

```
Array
(
    Площадь => 3028 м2,
    Тип дома => Каменный
    ...
    итд

)
```

Comment: проходишь циклом и каждый четный элемент - будет ключом в **новом** массиве, каждый нечетный - значением.

Comment: `array_chunk`? Не подойдет? По 2 разбить.

Answer (score 4):

Можно выполнить один проход циклом for:

```
$res = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($list); $i+=2) {
  $res[$list[$i]] = $list[$i+1];
}
```

Можно предварительно разбить исходный массив на чанки размером 2:

```
$chunks = array_chunk($list, 2);
$res = [];
foreach ($chunks as list($k, $v)) {
  $res[$k] = $v;
}
```

---

#### Более экзотичные способы.

**array_combine**:

```
$keys = array_filter($list, function($i){return ~$i&1;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$values = array_filter($list, function($i){return $i&1;}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
$res = array_combine($keys, $values);
```

**array_reduce**:

```
$res = array_reduce($list, function($c, $a) {
    if (is_null($c['key'])) $c['key'] = $a;
    else {
        $c['res'][$c['key']] = $a;
        $c['key'] = null;
    }
    return $c;
}, ['key' => null, 'res' => []])['res'];
```

*По условию, исходный массив имеет чётное количество элементов, если это не факт - желательно проверять наличие последнего чётного элемента*

Comment: Вот, теперь верну на место =) опередил. По 3 варианту.

Comment: @And, я тут судорожно думаю, как бы ещё извратиться)

Comment: меня отвлекли, и я опять не успел запостить с чанками :D

Comment: `$chunks as list($k, $v)` красивее будет

Comment: @teran, внесите правку, так в истории сохранится авторство(и +2 вроде за принятую правку)